# Why is SpringSecurityUtils null in this Grails unit test?

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

In Grails 2.0.4, I'm trying to write a controller unit test which invokes the static SpringSecurityUtils.reauthenticate. The test returns a NullPointerException on that invocation. In a debugger, I can see that none of the Groovy dynamic properties (declaredMethods,etc.) of SpringSecurityUtils are populated.

I do note that when running the tests, the "Configuring Spring Security Core" log message is emitted *after* the unit-test failure. Here is a sample test:

```java
class ReproTest {
    void testSpringSecurityUtils() {
        String.valueOf(true) // OK: a public final class from the JDK
        URLUtils.isRelativeURL("foo")  // OK: a class from another plugin
        SpringSecurityUtils.reauthenticate "user", "pw" // fails, NPE
    }
}
```

My initial reaction is that maybe plugins aren't accessible during unit tests, but if so, why is the URLUtils call working? And why does the test get "far enough" to initialize the plugin, but after the tests have completed?

Comment: Maybe http://nerderg.com/Grails helps you in your tests with SpringSecurity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a unit test the container isn't starting up.  No Spring injection or "grails goodness" is happening.  You see in the logs that the plugin is initializing after the unit tests run, because it [container] does start for the integration tests.  If you want to test the SpringSecurityUtils, although guessing it is already tested properly in the plugin, you would want to write an integration test.

Comment: Thank you! The goal of my test was to test a controller and SpringSecurityUtils was a means to that end, but I'll move that to an integration test. (I'm still confused about why a class from the resources plugin was available during unit-test, though.)

Comment: The code and dependencies would still be there.  Just none of the container/ spring dependency management.  Your call to URLUtils is a static call and probably has no other container managed dependencies, so it works.  Where the SpringSecurityUtils call probably has a dependency injected.  (Would have to look at the code to be sure, but guessing your test is failing due to something like an NPE?)

Comment: Correct, an NPE -- the code example above demonstrates it. SpringSecurityUtils.reauthenticate does indeed have a dependency injected (so it's a lost cause anyway) but the real puzzle to me is why SpringSecurityUtils wasn't getting groovified. Oh well, I'm happy to be puzzled sometimes.